# What is this parent (jboss-parent) that the parent pom in Wildfly Quickstart is pointing to?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, wildfly, wildfly-8

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-parent</artifactId>
    <version>14</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

Where should this parent go, once I find it?  Or is it safe to ignore?

Answer (score 1):

It's located on [GitHub](https://github.com/jboss/jboss-parent-pom/blob/master/pom.xml) and [Maven central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jboss%7Cjboss-parent%7C14%7Cpom).

You might not need it however depending on what you're doing. It's used to just pull in some default plugin versions and dependency versions.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the settings.xml file from $MAVEN_HOME/conf to local .m2 directory.

Edit and add:

inside `<profiles>` node:

```
    <profile>  
            <id>jboss-public-repository</id>  
            <repositories>  
                <repository>  
                    <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>  
                    <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>  
                    <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>  
                    <layout>default</layout>  
                    <releases>  
                        <enabled>true</enabled>  
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>  
                    </releases>  
                    <snapshots>  
                        <enabled>true</enabled>  
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>  
                    </snapshots>  
                </repository>  
            </repositories>  
            <pluginRepositories>  
                <pluginRepository>  
                    <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>  
                    <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>  
                    <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>  
                    <layout>default</layout>  
                    <releases>  
                        <enabled>true</enabled>  
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>  
                    </releases>  
                    <snapshots>  
                        <enabled>true</enabled>  
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>  
                    </snapshots>  
                </pluginRepository>  
            </pluginRepositories>  
        </profile>
```

Below `</profiles>` node in `<settings>` node:

```
    <activeProfiles>  
        <activeProfile>jboss-public-repository</activeProfile>  
    </activeProfiles>
```